# find equation for x halved, y gets doubled

Tags: arithmetic

How can I calculate a $y=f(x)$ formula for data like this:

```
x              y

10.000         0.016
5000           0.032
2500           0.064
```

so if $x$ is halved, $y$ gets doubled.

I think the formula is something like y = a/x + b

So i tried:

10000 = a/0.016 + b

and

5000 = a/0.032 + b

so

b = 10000 - a/0.016

in the second term

5000 = a/0.032 + 1000 - a/0.016     " * 0.016

80000 = a/2 + 16 - a

79984 = -a/2

a = -159968

b = 10000 - (-159968 / 0.016) = 19998

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: With all that doubling and halving, have you thought about what happens to the product $x\cdot y$?

Comment: Hint: If you're doubling the equation with each iteration, what factor would you use?

Comment: You multiplied wrong. $5000\times.016=80\neq80000$

Comment: Also you used $1000\times.016=16$ instead of $10000\times.016=160$

Comment: Otherwise, your approach would have worked, giving $a=160$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the coordinates $(x, y)$. All coordinates can be written in the form $\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nx, 2^ny\right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. However,

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nx \times 2^ny = xy$$

so $xy$ is constant.

In your case, $xy = 10000 \times 0.016 = 160$

Hence,

$$xf(x) = 160 \implies \boxed{f(x) = \frac{160}{x}}$$